# In a stimulus controller for a rails app, what is the proper way to get the element of a target

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

I am trying to put together a controller for changing the bottom border colour on a collection of tabs when one is clicked.

While it wasn't a problem to make a functioning controller, the way I had it written was very clunky and couldn't be expanded easily so I have changed the way it works to iterate through all targets and set their bottom border color to grey before going back and changing the one that was clicked to the highlight colour.

By passing event to the action I can do event.element to easily get the element of the target that was clicked.  this.constructor.targets gives me an array of the target names, and this.targets gives me a targetset object which I can't really work out how to manipulate or find any more info on. Because this.constructor.targets only gives me the name (eg. "home" rather than "homeTarget") I can't then call element on that I don't believe, so could anyone point me in the right direction of what I should be doing to get that element?

Here's my controller as it stands, which doesn't work, if I change this.targets to this.constructor.targets it still doesn't work but also gives the following error "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'borderBottomColor')" :

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {

static targets = ['home', 'groups', 'events', 'games'];




  connect(){
    console.log("Tab Controller Connected");
        
  }

  tabSelect(event){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.targets, targElement => {
      console.log(targElement)
      this.targElement.style.borderBottomColor = "var(--mainDark)"
    });
    event.target.style.borderBottomColor = "var(--highlight)"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `this.homeTarget.value` to get the value of `home` target.

Comment: Yes thank you, but I'm looking to iterate through an array of targets rather than call them by name. I ended up working round it by giving all targets the same name and then iterating through an array of those eg tabsTargets to remove the border highlight and then adding back the highlight on the event.target